# Defining complex static data in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access project where I am trying to define a lot of static data, I have details to load into a single very complex form.

I have setup types for this data:

```
Public Type ColumnData

    Name As String
    Width As Single
    Search As String * 1

End Type

Public Type FormData
    Form_Title As String
    View_Name As String
    Edit_Form As String
    ObjectSingular As String
    ObjectPlural As String
    Columns() As ColumnData
End Type
```

Is there a way I can add this data to a global variable in a module? The same way I would with basic data types:

```
Public Const g_LoggedIn As Boolean = False
Public Const g_APIKey As String = "ABC123"
Public Const g_TablePrefix as String = "auyhso_"
Public Const g_Columns As Variant = Array("1", "2", "3")
```

Something like:

```
Public g_FormData as Collection
g_FormData.Add New FormData(Form_Title:="My Title", View_Name:="My View")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be done. For one, this: `Public Const g_Columns As Variant = Array("1", "2", "3")` already doesn't work. `Array()` is a function. You can't have constant arrays.

VBA only supports simple data types as constants.

You can use a function that returns your constant instead of a constant, and accept the minor performance hit your application will take.

Comment: A function sounds possible, I'll take the performance hit over having hundreds of strings scattered all over my code!

Comment: This was a bit fiddly to setup but worked, performance hit is very low, thank you.